# Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, type-conversion

I am facing an error on my SQL script:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric

```
select x.MemberName,x.DOB,x.FilePath,x.Medication,x.NDC,x.Directions,x.Name,x.Strength,x.GenericName,x.QtyOrdered,x.DaysSupply,x.DateFilled, 
CASE
    WHEN x.test = 0  THEN 'N/A'
    WHEN compliance > 100.0   THEN '100.0'
    ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), CAST(FLOOR(compliance *10)/10.0 AS DECIMAL(3,1)))
END as [Compliance]
```

I am facing the error on just above syntax line.

Comment: and what values does column compliance hold?

Comment: it has values like 'N/A','100.0' or '99.1' ... i.e) it has both float and nvarchar

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
declare @compliance decimal(10,5)

set @compliance = 100.0  --  <----------------

select CAST(FLOOR(@compliance *10)/10.0 AS DECIMAL(3,1))
```

Throws "Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric" error. Changing to `DECIMAL(4,1)` works, or as @paola suggests, change your condition to `>= 100.0`

```
decimal(p,s):
```

> p (precision) is the maximum total number of decimal digits that will
>   be stored, both to the left and to the right of the decimal point. The
>   precision must be a value from 1 through the maximum precision of 38.
>   The default precision is 18.
>
> s (scale) is the number of decimal digits that will be stored to the
>   right of the decimal point. This number is subtracted from p to
>   determine the maximum number of digits to the left of the decimal
>   point.

In your case `decimal(3, 1)` means a total of 3 digits with 1 digit to the right of the decimal point,

```
99.9
```

whereas `decimal(4,1)` provides a total of 4 digits with 1 digit to the right of the decimal point,

```
999.9
```

Comment: @Compliance has to accept both NVARCHAR and FLOAT. i.e) If there is no Compliance .. we need to set it as N/A

Comment: I'm not suggesting otherwise.

Comment: @Chok, I think Mitch is right, you probably need to change your second case to `WHEN compliance >= 100.0` (note the >= )

Answer (score 5):

This questions has already been answered, but the *why* is important.

Numeric defines the TOTAL number of digits, and then the number after the decimal.

So DECIMAL(4,1)  shows 123.4
DECIMAL(4,3) shows 1.234

In both cases you have a total of 4 digits. In one case you have 1 after the decimal, leaving 3 in front of the decimal.  And vice versa.