# TSQL I don't understand Arithmetic Overflow Error Converting Money to Numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, type-conversion

A company is changing their DB systems, and I am in charge of preparing the data to go from the source DB to the target DB. One of the fields needs is the annual salary, and is going from a money datatype to a datatype of format "99999.999999".

I assumed something like the below would work. It first checks to see if the person is hourly, then put in 0. Otherwise, use the AnnlSal column and format for 6 points of precision.

```
UPDATE #SalaryInfo
SET AnnSalary = (SELECT CASE WHEN SalaryorHourly = 'H' THEN CONVERT(decimal(11,6), 0)
                             ELSE CONVERT(decimal(11,6), AnnlSal) 
                        END
                 FROM <table>
                 WHERE <table>.Emp = #SalaryInfo.EmpNo
```

That is giving me

> Arithmetic overflow error converting money to data type numeric.

I found [Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231660/arithmetic-overflow-error-converting-numeric-to-data-type-numeric), but I am not understanding why I am still having issues.

Comment: Try numeric(11,6). There is probably AnnlSal value that doesn't fit into decimal(11,6). Try to run MAX() and MIN() on AnnlSal

Comment: @IgorM Nope, same error :/

Comment: @JCark4321, did you try to run MAX() and MIN() on AnnlSal?

Comment: Maybe someone is being paid too much... does it go into decimal(12,6)?

Comment: According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx, it should cast implicitly

Comment: Duplicate of [Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231660/arithmetic-overflow-error-converting-numeric-to-data-type-numeric)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use a `decimal(11,6)`, your results cannot exceed $99,999.999999 for an annual salary. If one of your results hits $100,000 or above (`100000.000000`) will throw the overflow error.

Try using a few less points of precision. Maybe `decimal(11,3)` which should be enough for an Annual Salary.

Comment: Ah, you know what, that is the issue. I  I was given a test DB to work against, and one of the salaries was in the millions.  I already asked the "what if" question up the chain, but figured the conversion error was due to my code not a large salary value.

Comment: Note: when concerned with multicurrency (i.e., different countries money) and conversion you may need more than 3 decimal places. We had a case working between Euros and Dollars where the discounts and the taxes drove some of the amounts to have 4 and 5 digits on the right side.

Also note: do not use float when dealing with peoples' money, since it is not precise and you will not make your accounting team happy.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the error generated from the first or second CONVERT. Try following to track it down. You may have a null in the incoming data:

```
SET AnnSalary = (SELECT 
                     CASE WHEN SalaryorHourly = 'H' THEN 0
                          ELSE CONVERT(decimal(11,6), AnnlSal) 
                     END
                 FROM <table>
                 WHERE <table>.Emp = #SalaryInfo.EmpNo)
```

Comment: Pretty sure it is from the second one